# TFS Wrong file mapping

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs

I'm trying to use TFS but there is one problem:
I created project called `NewWeb` and added him to source control, after that I deleted this project and mapped `Global` to another project on cloud but one folder from still shown in the tree under the deleted project.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try deleting `$tf` (hidden) folder from your project folder.
- To avoid conflicts use `tfs destroy` command to destroy all the folders.
- Goto `File -> Source control -> Advenced -> Workspaces`, in the popup click edit and remap the folder where there should be.
- Check in pending changes.

Answer (score 3):

NewWeb is a separate Team Project, so has nothing to do with MVC4. You cannot map two source control folders to the same folder on your hard drive, so you can't have one folder shared by two team projects.

Instead, you will need the global stuff to be held in one place in source control and then referenced from there by your code solutions. Either use a separate Team Project for globals and each application, or have one Team Project for all your code, and place each app in its own subfolder.

finally, I'd advise that you try to minimise the mappings, I.e. map $/ to your hard drive so your workspace matches the source control layout. Using mappings to move things about Introduces complexity that leads to problems.

Comment: This is not what I meen. $/NewWeb/ is not exist on the server & also no mapping to it on local.[link](http://img22.imageshack.us/img22/1281/0ltn.png)

Comment: are you using a local workspace - Is it in your pending checkins? Other than that it looks like it is on your server...